# Understanding input/output operands in GCC inline assembly syntax

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, io

As part of writing my OS, I am implementing interrupt handling and the I/O functions `inb` and `outb`.

I had to learn writing inline assembly in GCC and read up a lot about it online. Based on my understanding, I wrote my own code. Meanwhile, I looked up Linux's implementation of the functions from `/usr/include/sys/io.h`. This is what it is like for `outb`:

```
static __inline void
outb (unsigned char __value, unsigned short int __port)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("outb %b0,%w1": :"a" (__value), "Nd" (__port));
}
```

Here are my questions:

- The GCC manual says "N" is

> Unsigned 8-bit integer constant (for in and out instructions).

But here `__port` is `unsigned short int` which I believe would be 16 bits. So how is it decided which portion of the 16 bits is used in the inline assembly ?

- This is my understanding of how this works - value of `__port` will be used directly (because of the "N") as a constant in place of %w1. Value of `__value` is copied to `eax`. %bo is replaced by %al. Then the instruction is executed. Is this correct ?
- How is it decided which of "N" or "d" to use for the second operand ? Is there some preference order ?
- What difference does it make if I don't use "N" ? Wouldn't simply using "d" be better, since that is 16 bits ?
- If I omitted the "N", then is it correct that value of `__port` is copied to `edx` and then %w1 is replaced by `edx` ?

Answer (score 2):

I may be mistaken, but my understanding is that `"Nd"` means use either `N` or `d`, at the compiler's preference. If the value is not known to be a constant that fits in 8 bits, then `N` is not satisfiable, so the compiler has no choice but to use `d`. But when the value is a compile-time constant and its value fits in 8 bits, using an 8-bit immediate is preferable to wasting a register.

Comment: That makes sense. It should be in the manual though, at least for beginners. Could you also say something about the other questions ?

Comment: Guess what, [it is in the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html): "*The simplest kind of constraint is a string full of letters, each of which describes one kind of operand that is permitted.*"